# GatsbyJS: StatiscQuery pass in data from current page

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I am trying to createPages programmatically in GatsbyJS. I have made a herotext component to my page template.  The issue I am having is that static queries don't seem to support graphql variables. How can I get data from the page in my GraphQL query?

My GraphQL query:

```
query HeroById($id: String) {
          wpPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
            ACFundersider {
              hero {
                heroText
                heroHeading
              }
            }
            id
          }
        }
```

The variable `id: { eq: $id })` that doesn't seem to take any effect at all. I have noticed there is a query to get currentPage but not quite sure if I can use that?

```
query MyQuery {
  wpPage(ACFundersider: {hero: {heroText: {}}}) {
    allWpPage {
      pageInfo {
        currentPage
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My component looks like this with StaticQuery:

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

export default function HeroText() {
  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={graphql`
        query HeroById($id: String) {
          wpPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
            ACFundersider {
              hero {
                heroText
                heroHeading
              }
            }
            id
          }
        }
      `}
      render={data => <h2>{data.wpPage.ACFundersider.hero.heroHeading}</h2>}
    />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`staticQuery` (or `useStaticQuery` hook) doesn't accept parameters (hence the name, static), as you can see in [Gatsby docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/querying-data/static-query/#how-staticquery-differs-from-page-query). Your approach will never work.

To use your `HeroById` query, you need to use the context to pass the `id` to the page and use a [page query](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=page%20query%20gatsby) rather than a static query. Your full code should look like:

```
import * as React from 'react'
import { graphql } from 'gatsby'

const SomeTemplate= ({data}) => {
  console.log("your data is", data);
  return (
    <div>
     Some content
    </div>
  )
}

export const query = graphql`
        query HeroById($id: String) {
          wpPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
            ACFundersider {
              hero {
                heroText
                heroHeading
              }
            }
            id
          }
        }
      `

export default SomeTemplate
```

Check the GraphQL query in the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to ensure that your `HeroById` query returns something when filtering by `id` (try hardcoding the `id` if you can).

Answer (score 0):

Can you access your query through nodes or edges? If you're using nodes you can try to do something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import { StaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

const query = graphql`
        query HeroById($id: String) {
          wpPage(id: { eq: $id }) {
            ACFundersider {
              hero {
                heroText
                heroHeading
              }
            }
            id
          }
         }
`

export default function HeroText() {
    const data = useStaticQuery(query)
    const { wpPage: { nodes: pages }, } = data
    return (
        <div>
            {
                pages.map(page => {
                    return (
                        <h2>page.ACFundersider.hero.heroHeading</h2>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
)}
```

Not sure if this exact code works for you (you might want to tweak it a bit).